# QSpiAccessible messages

Tags: qt

I have a project in Qt which was working fine, but suddenly it started to print these messages in the application output.

The project runs fine in spite of these messages.

```
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-YK3RLJzcQV,guid=68c6855978ee42309292618f51127852" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-YK3RLJzcQV,guid=68c6855978ee42309292618f51127852" 
Registered DEC:  true 
Registered event listener change listener:  true 
QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "2"  obj:  QMessageBox(0xbfa787bc) "" 
FIXME: handle dialog start. 
FIXME: handle dialog end.
```

Comment: sadly, I cannot use my crystal ball at the moment.

Comment: @UmNyobe Turns out I can use mine. :)

Comment: @UmNyobe: indeed, it is difficult to say without code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtiplot/+bug/997462) in qt-ai-spi package. Try removing that package from your system.

Comment: Thanks. I fugured that out 30 sec before your answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SamuelNLP Glad you made it:). I would be faster if the stackoverflow didn't wanted to check if I am one of the people dressed up in aluminium foil, which it is referring as robots.

Answer (score 2):

Removing a QT accessibility package (qt-at-spi) works.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge qt-at-spi
```